# How to fix text in my svg file?

Tags: svg, text-manipulation

I am working in Overleaf with a `memoir` document class. Recently I have already inserted successfully in my document an svg image that comes from a simple download on internet.
This time I had to draw a diagram and export it in svg (from Visual Paradigm Online), and I visualize it right:

[image: The svg diagram i normally see]

but there is a problem when I insert it in my LaTeX document with

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includesvg{Untitled.svg}
\end{figure}
```

I see it this way:

[image: The svg diagram in the LaTeX document]

As you can see, I have two problems (the second one is solved):

1. The words "System", "Actor", "UseCase" are overlapped
2. The two Visual Paradigm watermarks (I have simply deleted the text tag in the svg file)

And it seemed tricky to me that the watermark is fixed while the other text is not, indeed, these are built with some different tags. Now I can't figure out how the three words can be fixed in the place they should be, I leave here the "System" word svg code:

```
<g shape-node="">
<g cell-id="fL3SQjhoObUfCc7ECOGH-1" transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
    <switch cell-id="fL3SQjhoObUfCc7ECOGH-1">
        <foreignObject cell-id="fL3SQjhoObUfCc7ECOGH-1" style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe flex-start; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 27px; margin-left: 153px;">
                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; ">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;VP Default&quot;; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; word-break: break-word; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">
                        <div ani="">
                            System
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%">
            <defs>
                <path id="XKT4o6GDkP1cNABn" d="M231.9875030517578,39.6 h40.01250076293945"/>
            </defs>
            <text fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica, &quot;VP Default&quot;" font-weight="400">
                <textPath xlink:href="#XKT4o6GDkP1cNABn" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
                    <tspan xml:space="preserve">
                        System
                    </tspan>
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </switch>
</g>
```

Adopted a "solution":
Text added in Inkscape is visualized right when I include the svg in the document.

Comment: How does it look when you open the svg file in Inkscape? Maybe you can correct the wrong layout there and save the SVG again?

Comment: @Marijn Trying it all now with some Inkscape tools, but can't...

Comment: Without a MWE to test, my suggestions are: (1) save the image as PDF without saving text in a LaTeX file, then insert in LaTeX with `\includegraphics` as you do with PNG or JPG images, or alternatively (2) if match LaTeX fonts is "a must", be sure that you are not scaling the image in LaTeX, e.g., if the image in the  document should have a width of 8 cm with texts of 12pt, in Inkscape the  SVG image also must have 8 cm and any text also must have 12pt of a  not very different font.

Comment: I've removed the `memoir` tag as this is not related to memoir